# Mapping the "lower diagonal" of a tensor to a matrix, as a generalization of the extraction of the lower triangular part of a matrix into a vector

Tags: c++, tensor

Given a rank-4 tensor (each rank with dimension `K`), for example `T(p,q,r,s)`, we can 1-to-1 map all the tensor elements into a matrix of dimension `K^2 x K^2`, for example `M(i,j)` in which the two first tensor indices `p,q` and the last two indices `r,s` are combined in a column major way:

```
i = p + K * q
j = r + K * s
```

Exploiting some (anti-)symmetries of the given tensor, for example `T(p,q,r,s) = -T(q,p,r,s) = -T(p,q,s,r) = T(q,p,s,r)` and `T(p,q,r,s) = T(r,s,p,q)`, we would like to be able to construct a matrix `H(m,n)` that only contains the unique elements (i.e. those not related by the previously defined symmetries), such that `p>q` and `r>s` into the matrix `H(m,n)`, which would then be of dimension `K(K-1)/2 x K(K-1)/2`.

How could we find an algorithm (or even better: how can we use the C++ library Eigen) to accomplish these index transformations? Furthermore, can we write down `m` and `n` algebraically in terms of `p,q` and `r,s`, like we can do in the case where we would want to extract the strict lower triangular matrix (no diagonal) into a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, given a square matrix `Eigen::MatrixXd M (K,K)`, here is an algorithm that extracts the strict lower triangle of a given square matrix M into a vector m of size, using the C++ `Eigen` library:

```
    Eigen::VectorXd strictLowerTriangle(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M) {

    auto K = static_cast<size_t>(M.cols());  // the dimension of the matrix
    Eigen::VectorXd m = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero((K*(K-1)/2));  // strictly lower triangle has K(K-1)/2 parameters

    size_t vector_index = 0;
    for (size_t q = 0; q < K; q++) {  // "column major" ordering for, so we do p first, then q
        for (size_t p = q+1; p < K; p++) {
            m(vector_index) = M(p,q);
            vector_index++;
        }
    }

    return m;
}
```

We are able to extend this algorithm to the requested general case:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd strictLowerTriangle(const Eigen::Tensor<double, 4>& T) {

    auto K = static_cast<size_t> (dims[0]);

    Eigen::MatrixXd M (K*(K-1)/2, K*(K-1)/2);

    size_t row_index = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < K; j++) {  // "column major" ordering for row_index<-i,j so we do j first, then i
        for (size_t i = j+1; i < K; i++) {  // in column major indices, columns are contiguous, so the first of two indices changes more rapidly
                                                  // require i > j

            size_t column_index = 0;
            for (size_t l = 0; l < K; l++) {  // "column major" ordering for column_index<-k,l so we do l first, then k
                for (size_t k = l+1; k < K; k++) {  // in column major indices, columns are contiguous, so the first of two indices changes more rapidly
                                                          // require l > k

                    M(row_index,column_index) = T(i,j,k,l);

                    column_index++;
                }
            }

            row_index++;
        }
    }

    return M;
}
```

Comment: This ignores the `T(p,q,r,s) = T(r,s,p,q)` symmetry, right?

Comment: @chtz, I think this even ignores any symmetry at all: I believe this is just a general way of extracting the "lower triangle" of a general KxKxKxK tensor.

Comment: Even though this does not specifically use any of the symmetries listed, this transformation is exactly what I was looking for, which is why I will accept this answer.